# How to make listings connected?

Tags: compiling, tcolorbox

In the example below, `\Baz` in listing 2. is supposed to depend on `\Foo` in listing 1., but doing so causes an error. Is there a way to connect the two? In other words, is it possible to break up a (long) listing into sub-listings?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable}
\newtcblisting[auto counter]
{listing}[2][]{
  noparskip,
  breakable,
  title=Listing~\thetcbcounter. #1,
  listing and text,
  %text only,
  #2
}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:foo}
  \NewDocumentCommand\Foo{}{Foo}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:baz}
  \NewDocumentCommand\Baz{}{\Foo}
  \Baz
  % ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
%
%--- TeX said ---
%\Baz code ->\Foo 
%                 
%l.2   \Baz
%          % \Baz code ->\Foo
%
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable}
\newtcblisting[auto counter]
{listing}[2][]{
  noparskip,
  breakable,
  title=Listing~\thetcbcounter. #1,
  listing and text,
  %text only,
  #2
}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:foo}
  \NewDocumentCommand\Foo{}{Foo}
\end{listing}
\NewDocumentCommand\Foo{}{Foo}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:baz}
  \NewDocumentCommand\Baz{}{\Foo}
  \Baz
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As the most famous cat in the world said in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537770/203621), `\Foo` is defined locally, so the definition doesn't survive when the environment ends. If you want to use it outside the environment, you need to define the command in an outer scope.

Instead of using `\def`-like commands, which will produce a different listing from what you want, I just repeat the definition after the environment ends. It makes sure that your listing is left unchanged.

Comment: Yeah, or something like `\AfterEndEnvironment{listing}{\hook}` and for each listing, `\gappto{\hook}{code}`, within.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you define `\Foo` *locally*. If you make it global, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable}
\newtcblisting[auto counter]
{listing}[2][]{
  noparskip,
  breakable,
  title=Listing~\thetcbcounter. #1,
  listing and text,
  %text only,
  #2
}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:foo}
  \xdef\Foo{Foo}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:baz}
  \edef\Baz{\Foo}
  \Baz
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *could*, but absolutely should *not*, make the `\NewDocumentCommand` global.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable}
\newtcblisting[auto counter]
{listing}[2][]{
  noparskip,
  breakable,
  title=Listing~\thetcbcounter. #1,
  listing and text,
  %text only,
  #2
}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:foo}
  \globaldefs1
  \NewDocumentCommand\Foo{}{Foo}
  \globaldefs0
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}[]
  {label=listing:baz}
  \NewDocumentCommand\Baz{}{\Foo}
  \Baz
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

This does work but is also one of the most efficient ways of opening Pandora's box. This example is only added to show that the locality is the problem but you should absolutely not use it for any code that has the purpose of typesetting stable documents.